# Double conditional expectation Problem!

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, expected-value

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be independent Random Variables and let $Z:=f(X_1,...,X_n)$, where f is a function $ f: \Omega^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $.
Let $Z \in \mathcal{L}^2$ and denote $E^{(i)}[Z] := E[Z \vert X_1,...,X_{i-1},X_{i+1},...,X_n] $ and $E_{(i)}[Z] := E[Z \vert X_1,...,X_i] $.

I already proved: $E^{(i)}[E_{(i)}[Z]]=E_{(i-1)}[Z]$.
with this i need to prove:
\begin{equation*}
E[Var^{(i)}(E_{(i)}[Z])]=E[E_{(i)}[Z]^2-E_{(i-1)}[Z]^2]
\end{equation*}

My Attempt was:
\begin{align*}
E[Var^{(i)}(E_{(i)}[Z])]&=E[E^{(i)}[E_{(i)}[Z]^2]-E^{(i)}[E_{(i)}[Z]]^2] \\
&= E[E^{(i)}[E_{(i)}[Z]^2]-E_{(i-1)}[Z]^2]
\end{align*}
but now i dont know what i can do with this $E^{(i)}[E_{(i)}[Z]^2]$ Term. I tried to show with the defintion of the conditional expectation that:
$E^{(i)}[E_{(i)}[Z]^2]=E_{(i)}[Z]^2$ but i failed. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

For an integrable random variable $Y$ and a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$, 
$$
\mathbb E\left[\mathbb E\left[X\mid \mathcal F\right]\right]=\mathbb E\left[X\right].
$$
Apply this to 
$$
X= \left(E_{(i)}[Z]\right)^2;\quad \mathcal F:=\sigma\left( X_1,...,X_{i-1},X_{i+1},...,X_n\right).
$$